# Running a rails server in production locally (InvalidMessage error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production

I'm running Ruby 2.5.1 and Rails 5.2.0. I ran `rails s -e production`, and it gives this error:

```
/home/roy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:206:in `rescue in_decrypt': ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage
(ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage)
```

How do I do this properly?

---

**EDIT:**
The same error appears whenever I try to edit the credentials file using

```
EDITOR="nano --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit
```

Also I realized that I didn't create a production database yet so I tried that using

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails db:reset
```

(I know db:reset is a bit redundant but it should work trying to create, migrate and seed a server)

Sadly I get the same kind of error (InvalidMessage error)

```
Unsupported rails environment for compass
rake aborted!
ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage
/home/roy/apps/myappname/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
/home/roy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/roy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'

Caused by:
OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError: 
/home/roy/apps/myappname/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
/home/roy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/roy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:create => db:load_config => environment
```

Comment: Do you use encrypted secrets file?

Comment: No, but I tried using that. Whenever I run `EDITOR="nano --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit` to edit the encrypted credentials it gives me the same error as seen in my post.

Comment: do you have `master.key` of your app?

Comment: @AntonTkachov yes, I do have one

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Okay I got it working finally.

I simply deleted my `master.key` and `credentials.yml.enc` files and then ran

```
bin/rails credentials:edit
```

Which created new files. After that everything worked fine.

I don't really understand why it works though. Can anyone give a good explanation for this?

Comment: Thanks, but just deleting the files isn't a decent solution. What if you can't lose the saved encrypted credentials? :)

Comment: thanks for saving Rails stupid setting. those stuip setup kills rails

Comment: you saved my day :) I was deleting only `credentials.yml.enc` and it wasn't working for me until I read that you deleted master.key as well, so for anyone who read this, don't forget to delete both `master.key` and `credentials.yml.enc`

Comment: I believe credentials are encrypted using `ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor`. Some rails upgrades change the default cipher used by that class. So when you try to use the old one it fails to decrypt the secrets. 
I was using `ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor` directly and I fix this by using the option to rotate ciphers (https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveSupport/MessageEncryptor.html) I'm not sure why this is not an option for credentials.yml.enc
My guess is that this solution works because it encrypts the secrets again with the new cipher.

Answer (score 9):

It appears your solution of removing the `master.key` and `credentials.yml.enc` indicates you are running Rails 5.2. This setup changed from a similar encrypted `secrets.yml.enc` file used in Rails 5.1.

The goal is to allow committing secret keys (AWS, Rails' `secrect_key_base`) to a project's code repository. These would typically be set with ENV variables. Now collaborators need only share the `master.key` that was generated to decrypt and modify or read the contents of `credentials.yml.enc`.

When you removed both the `master.key` and `credentials.yml.enc` files, rails generated a new pair, now you were able to decrypt `credentials.yml.enc` and this file was initialized with a new Rails `secret_key_base` value needed to avoid the `ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage`. If you track down the source of that message, it's likely referencing the Rails credentials secret key base: `Rails.application.credentials.secret_key_base`.

These are nice write ups on the topic:
https://medium.com/cedarcode/rails-5-2-credentials-9b3324851336
https://www.engineyard.com/blog/rails-encrypted-credentials-on-rails-5.2

Answer (score 2):

For Rails 6, I had a multi-environment credentials setup.

One for development, staging, and production.

The master.key works for the main `credentials.yml` file

The other environments have there own key, so for staging we used the production.key in place of the `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` config envs on heroku and that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this similar issue when working with a Rails 5 application in production, [royketelaar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50117332/10907864) and [gib's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52344673/10907864)

Just to add a few things:

After deleting the `credentials.yml.enc` and `master.key` files,

And running the command below to generate a new `secret_key_base`, `credentials.yml.enc` and `master.key` files (my editor is VS Code and not Nano):

```
EDITOR="code --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit
```

Ensure that uncomment the following configuration in your `config/environments/production.rb` file:

```
config.require_master_key = true
```

For your production environment, since the `master.key` file containing the `master key` which is used for decrypting the `credentials.yml.enc` is not recommended to be committed to version system control, save the `master key` in a `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` environment variable using the [figaro](https://rubygems.org/gems/figaro) gem.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask for the master key to you project leader / team leader / coworkers.

With that long key like 63y4gh47373h3733jj474 you copy it and paste it the master.key file under config folder.

That solve the issue.