# Rails: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Help me please, I've finished 11 chapters of the rails tutorial, deployed my app to heroku (locally it worked perfectly) and it crashing all time. I'm using rails 5.2.2
After execution of command $heroku run rails console I'm receiving this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    92: from /app/bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
    91: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    90: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    89: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    88: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    87: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    86: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    85: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    84: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    83: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    82: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    81: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    80: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
     6: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:21:in `read'
     5: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:42:in `read'
     4: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:79:in `decrypt'
     3: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:21:in `decrypt_and_verify'
     2: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:157:in `decrypt_and_verify'
     1: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:183:in `_decrypt'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:206:in `rescue in _decrypt': ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage (ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage)
```

Also, I've read this topic [Running a rails server in production locally (InvalidMessage error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50102639/running-a-rails-server-in-production-locally-invalidmessage-error) and haven't found files  master.key and credentials.yml.enc on my PC.

Also here is my production config:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Ensures that a master key has been made available in either ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]
  # or in config/master.key. This key is used to decrypt credentials (and other encrypted files).
  # config.require_master_key = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options)
  config.active_storage.service = :local

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "sample_app_#{Rails.env}"

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  host = 'calm-spire-36002.herokuapp.com'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

And I'm receiving these errors when deploying to heroku:

```
Counting objects: 23, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (23/23), done.
Writing objects: 100% (23/23), 2.17 KiB | 1.08 MiB/s, done.
Total 23 (delta 16), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.5.3
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Your Gemfile lists the gem pg (>= 0) more than once.
remote:        You should probably keep only one of them.
remote:        While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of one of them later.
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.17.2). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
remote:        Using rake 12.3.2
remote:        Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.4
remote:        Using minitest 5.11.3
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Using builder 3.2.3
remote:        Using erubi 1.8.0
remote:        Using mini_portile2 2.4.0
remote:        Using crass 1.0.4
remote:        Using rack 2.0.6
remote:        Using nio4r 2.3.1
remote:        Using websocket-extensions 0.1.3
remote:        Using mini_mime 1.0.1
remote:        Using arel 9.0.0
remote:        Using mimemagic 0.3.3
remote:        Using execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Using bcrypt 3.1.12
remote:        Using msgpack 1.2.6
remote:        Using rb-fsevent 0.10.3
remote:        Using ffi 1.10.0
remote:        Using will_paginate 3.1.6
remote:        Using bundler 1.15.2
remote:        Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
remote:        Using method_source 0.9.2
remote:        Using thor 0.20.3
remote:        Using multi_json 1.13.1
remote:        Using pg 1.1.4
remote:        Using puma 3.12.0
remote:        Using tilt 2.0.9
remote:        Using turbolinks-source 5.2.0
remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.5
remote:        Using nokogiri 1.10.0
remote:        Using rack-test 1.1.0
remote:        Using i18n 0.9.5
remote:        Using sprockets 3.7.2
remote:        Using websocket-driver 0.7.0
remote:        Using autoprefixer-rails 9.4.4
remote:        Using uglifier 4.1.20
remote:        Using marcel 0.3.3
remote:        Using mail 2.7.1
remote:        Using rb-inotify 0.10.0
remote:        Using coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Using turbolinks 5.2.0
remote:        Using bootstrap-will_paginate 1.0.0
remote:        Using bootsnap 1.3.2
remote:        Using loofah 2.2.3
remote:        Using activesupport 5.2.2
remote:        Using faker 1.7.3
remote:        Using sass-listen 4.0.0
remote:        Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.4
remote:        Using sass 3.7.3
remote:        Using bootstrap-sass 3.3.7
remote:        Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
remote:        Using globalid 0.4.2
remote:        Using activemodel 5.2.2
remote:        Using jbuilder 2.8.0
remote:        Using activerecord 5.2.2
remote:        Using actionview 5.2.2
remote:        Using actionpack 5.2.2
remote:        Using activejob 5.2.2
remote:        Using actioncable 5.2.2
remote:        Using activestorage 5.2.2
remote:        Using railties 5.2.2
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
remote:        Using actionmailer 5.2.2
remote:        Using coffee-rails 4.2.2
remote:        Using jquery-rails 4.3.3
remote:        Using rails 5.2.2
remote:        Using sass-rails 5.0.7
remote:        Bundle complete! 31 Gemfile dependencies, 68 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Bundle completed (3.30s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote:        Your Gemfile lists the gem pg (>= 0) more than once.
remote:        You should probably keep only one of them.
remote:        While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of one of them later.
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.17.2). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        The latest bundler is 2.0.1, but you are currently running 1.15.2.
remote:        To update, run `gem install bundler`
remote: -----> Installing node-v10.14.1-linux-x64
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:206:in `rescue in _decrypt'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:183:in `_decrypt'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:157:in `decrypt_and_verify'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:21:in `decrypt_and_verify'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:79:in `decrypt'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:42:in `read'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:21:in `read'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:33:in `config'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:38:in `options'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb:271:in `method_missing'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/config/environments/production.rb:100:in `block in <main>'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:216:in `instance_eval'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:216:in `configure'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/config/environments/production.rb:1:in `<main>'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:602:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:601:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:601:in `block in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:520:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        
remote:        Caused by:
remote:        OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError: 
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:201:in `final'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:201:in `_decrypt'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:157:in `decrypt_and_verify'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:21:in `decrypt_and_verify'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:79:in `decrypt'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:42:in `read'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:21:in `read'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:33:in `config'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:38:in `options'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb:271:in `method_missing'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/config/environments/production.rb:100:in `block in <main>'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:216:in `instance_eval'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:216:in `configure'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/config/environments/production.rb:1:in `<main>'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:602:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:601:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:601:in `block in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:520:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_f2f890d3b7847e0537bd079a0d608e14/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to cryptic-chamber-73265.
remote: 
To heroku.com:cryptic-chamber-73265.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:cryptic-chamber-73265.git'
```

Comment: Did you follow the heroku guide (for rails) to set up your app properly? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5 .

Comment: Yes, of course. I did it

Comment: do you have this SENDGRID_USERNAME env variables on your .enc file?

Comment: For those coming here from Google wondering how to get Heroku to use your production key: https://blog.dennishackethal.com/2020/12/31/using-rails-production-credentials-with-heroku.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the only way for me was to renew my master key.

1. copy your decrypted credentials
2. remove the files
3. regenerate key
4. read the datas

This post help me https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32718

Answer (score 64):

Here are the docs for environmental security on rails https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#environmental-security

In your case, you should have these files

```
config/master.key
config/credentials.yml.enc
```

Delete those files and then you can generate them with this:

```
rails credentials:edit --wait
```

While the credentials are open, note the master.key string, and then close the editor.

If you have not set the editor, you may need to do

```
EDITOR="your_editor_name --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit
```

The file master.key should be ignored by your version control because it is the key rails uses to decrypt the .enc, just commit your credentials.yml.enc and push it to heroku.

For master.key on heroku you can define the environment variable RAILS_MASTER_KEY on your heroku app and set it to the value of master.key.

Now to access the environments variables that you defined on your .enc file you must access them through Rails.application.credentials

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => Rails.application.credentials.SENDGRID_USERNAME,
    :password       => Rails.application.credentials.SENDGRID_PASSWORD,
    :domain         => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Comment: Did you checked for this files on your project config/master.key
config/credentials.yml.enc ?

Comment: I just modified the contents of my master.key and tried to run the rails credentials:edit and got the same error. When it tries to decrypt the contents of credentials.yml.enc and the key doesn't work it raises that exception

Comment: To put the value of master.key to my heroku app RAILS_MASTER_KEY variable I need first to decrypt master.key file? (because value is like "d8d7ffda738459e85a4dbe9be406cb8a")

Comment: No, that's the key, put that value in the RAILS_MASTER_KEY variable

Comment: I'm doing all things right? https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WdVDKiDKOxZhb9IBTAhF8tyni2S8rTJQ Because after that changes I can't deploy my app to heroku :(

Comment: update the value of your secret_key_base, if you generated a new master.key and credentials.yml.enc, now your add has a new value for secret_key_base on the encrypted file

Comment: If I understood correct I need also update the value of  secret_key_base -> this value I need to to take from newly generated credentials.yml.enc file? (current key in my heroku app has 1,5 rows of digits and key in credentials.yml.enc has 6 rows of digits) o_O

Comment: Yes that's correct, did you pushed your new credentials.yml.enc file to heroku?

Comment: Yeah, I did it. But I'm devastated. Now I can't push to heroku. I receive error: remote : ! Precompiling assets failed. And this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19650621/heroku-upload-precompiling-assets-failed doesn't help me

Comment: Can you put your error stack trace on your question?

Comment: Sure, it starts from "And I'm receiving these errors when deploying to heroku:"

Comment: I would recommend precompiling assets for production on your local pc and then push the changes. Notice that you are still receiving the same error

Answer (score 47):

1. Remove the credentials:

```
rm -rf config/credentials.yml.enc
```

2. Create a new credentials:

```
  EDITOR="mate --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit
```

Hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 25):

For me, it was because the environmental variable (found in the Heroku Settings page in the 'Config Vars' section) held an outdated master key.

**Starting with Rails 6, you can have credentials per environment. So, I had credentials for production that differed from those in development; and both of these credentials have their own master key.**

The one found here: `config/master.key`, is for the standard credentials file: `config/credentials.yml.enc`. The credentials file for production found here: `config/credentials/production.yml.enc` is encrypted with the `production.key` found in the same folder here: `config/credentials/production.key`.

I updated the key in Heroku in the Config Vars to the new `production.key` and everything deployed correctly.

**I hope that this helps. Happy Coding!**

*Also, I would recommend, after updating any Config Vars, to restart your dynos on Heroku. This insures that any new environmental variables are taken into account.

To do this, click on the 'More' button in the top right of any page, and then click on 'Restart all dynos'.

Comment: It's for rails 5.2, Answering with a solutions for a different version is counter to what the OP wants. You can't just expect them to upgrade a rails version to suit your solution.

Comment: to add another perspective Richard, it was helpful to me! (a casual googler that _is_ on rails 6)

Comment: How do you create a production.key and productions.yml.enc files? I do not have them. I have only the standard ones master.key and credentials.yml.enc.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It helped fix my issue. I needed to set my Heroku config var to the key in `config/credentials/production.key`. The main project master key in `config/master` wasn't working

Comment: @Yuriy, you can run `rails credentials:edit --environment production` to get the production files. Checking this blog that does a great job explaining the various credential files: https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/10/10/rails-6-adds-support-for-multi-environment-credentials#create-credentials-for-production-environment

Comment: @Richard and MaxRah, I’m glad my answer could help you both! Happy Coding!

Answer (score 9):

I had this issue when working on a Rails 6 application in Ubuntu 20.04.

The issue was that I was setting/specifying a wrong `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` environment variable in my `.env` files in **development** (`.env`, `.env.development`). I just wanted to use it as a placeholder temporarily since I did not need it in my **development** environment.

This was then throwing the error below when I run a rails command, say `rails generate uploader ProductImage`:

> `rescue in _decrypt': ActiveSupport::MessageEncry
> ptor::InvalidMessage (ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage)

And even when I try generating a new `master.key` and the `credentials.yml.enc` files using `rails credentials:edit` or `EDITOR="code --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit` it throws the error below:

```
key=': key must be 16 bytes (ArgumentError)
```

**Here's how to fix it**:

What you have to do is to either provide the correct `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` environment variable in the `.env` file(s) or comment out the `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` environment variable if you are not using it.

That's it.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: Note for Rails 6: If you're generating credentials on a per environment basis then one should set the RAILS_MASTER_KEY to the production.key NOT the master.key. You will only have a master.key if you also (accidentally) generated a credentials file without specifying an environment.  If you have both, the environments (production.key) take precedence over the master.key.

Comment: @RJaus, on behalf of the entire BreakDiving.io team, we thank you.  After 5 months (yes, 5 months) of trying to get SES to work, and trying to figure out Rails Credentials, your tiny comment here was the only explanation on all of the internet that solved the problem.  No where on the Rails docs does it say that the Master Key is useless if you use keys on an environmental basis.  For 3 weeks working with the AWS team, even they had no idea how to solve this problem.  Finally, today, our members can finally... reset their password!  You should feel very proud of yourself.  We are so grateful.

Comment: I had this issue when working on a Rails 6 application in Ubuntu 18.04. Your solution helps me. Thanks!

Comment: @RJaus This ... sounds bonkers ... and it IS bonkers, that it was just what made my stuff work, too ... :-D Thanks loads! (Debian 10 for me)

Answer (score 4):

1 Delete this 2 files:

```
config/master.key
config/credentials.yml.enc
```

2 Run this command:

```
EDITOR="nano" bundle exec rails credentials:edit
```

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same problems a few moments later. Also, find a solution for me! basically, I'm using an android device for developing a Ruby on Rails app. the solution is:
go to the app config directory. Then backup and remove the following files:

```
master.key
credentials.yml.enc
```

then go to terminal or on android, go to termux and write the command on app directory (must check you are on the rails app directory):

```
$ EDITOR=nano rails credentials:edit
```

you can also use other editors like Atom on desktops. now a new master.key and temporary non-encrypted credentials file will be created in terminal or termux (for android users). then press "ctrl+x" then "y" And then press enter, then the temporary non-encrypted credential file will be encrypted. now try to do your work. Now you might get a successful output. That's all.
Happy Coding.

Notes: some points I get help for writing this answer from:
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32718

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask for the master key to you project leader / team leader / coworkers.

With that long key like 3823729sdad29323832idsd you copy it and paste it the  master.key file under config folder.

That solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of Active record encryption keys are needed, following command can generate those.

```
rails db:encryption:init
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue today, I found that I merge new credentials.yml.enc, so I tried to open EDITOR="code . --wait" rails credentials:edit getting the error listed here.

The solution for me was only deleting that extra empty line in the end of the file, that line was added after merging branches with vs code.

Answer (score 0):

All my credentials were set properly, but I had forgot to set the master key in heroku.

#### How to set the master key on heroku

Go to `/config/master.key`, copy/paste the master key from the file then set it like so:

```sh
heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=c9102a13496fdc09430445a6602e3j85
```

Comment: Where exactly do you set hits on Heroku? Please, specify!

Answer (score 0):

delete this file in config/credentials.yml.enc and create a new one using
EDITOR="mate --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit