# How to run rails server in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to deploy my rails 6.1 app in production mode but with the production environment flag, I got errors. I don't understand how to configure properly rails for production.
So I have tried to make migration like that :

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create db:migrate db:seed
```

but I have got this error :

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create db:migrate db:seed
rake aborted!
ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:203:in `rescue in _decrypt'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:180:in `_decrypt'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:154:in `decrypt_and_verify'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:22:in `decrypt_and_verify'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:92:in `decrypt'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:54:in `read'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:21:in `read'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:33:in `config'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:38:in `options'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb:309:in `method_missing'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/application.rb:431:in `secret_key_base'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/application.rb:177:in `key_generator'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/globalid-0.4.2/lib/global_id/railtie.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:68:in `block in execute_hook'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:61:in `with_execution_control'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:66:in `execute_hook'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:140:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/application.rb:384:in `initialize!'
/home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/application.rb:360:in `require_environment!'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/application.rb:526:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'

Caused by:
OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError: 
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:198:in `final'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:198:in `_decrypt'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:154:in `decrypt_and_verify'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:22:in `decrypt_and_verify'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:92:in `decrypt'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:54:in `read'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:21:in `read'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:33:in `config'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:38:in `options'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb:309:in `method_missing'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/application.rb:431:in `secret_key_base'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/application.rb:177:in `key_generator'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/globalid-0.4.2/lib/global_id/railtie.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:68:in `block in execute_hook'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:61:in `with_execution_control'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:66:in `execute_hook'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:140:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/application.rb:384:in `initialize!'
/home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/application.rb:360:in `require_environment!'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/application.rb:526:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:create => db:load_config => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

and when I try to run the server like that :

```
rails s -e production
```

I have this error :

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.1.3.1 application starting in production 
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
        107: from bin/rails:2:in `<main>'
        106: from bin/rails:2:in `load'
        105: from /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
        104: from /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/bin/spring:7:in `tap'
        103: from /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
        102: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
        101: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
        100: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
         99: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
         98: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
         97: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
         96: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
         95: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
         94: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
         93: from /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
         92: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
         91: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
         90: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
         89: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
         88: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
         87: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
         86: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/command.rb:50:in `invoke'
         85: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
         84: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
         83: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
         82: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
         81: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `perform'
         80: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `tap'
         79: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:144:in `block in perform'
         78: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:39:in `start'
         77: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:311:in `start'
         76: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:379:in `handle_profiling'
         75: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:312:in `block in start'
         74: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
         73: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
         72: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
         71: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
         70: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
         69: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
         68: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
         67: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
         66: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require_relative'
         65: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
         64: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
         63: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
         62: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
         61: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
         60: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
         59: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
         58: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
         57: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
         56: from /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
         55: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/application.rb:384:in `initialize!'
         54: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
         53: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
         52: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
         51: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
         50: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
         49: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
         48: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
         47: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
         46: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
         45: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
         44: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
         43: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
         42: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
         41: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:133:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
         40: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:508:in `eager_load_all'
         39: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:508:in `each'
         38: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:393:in `eager_load'
         37: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:393:in `synchronize'
         36: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:404:in `block in eager_load'
         35: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:725:in `ls'
         34: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:725:in `foreach'
         33: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:733:in `block in ls'
         32: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:409:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load'
         31: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:409:in `const_get'
         30: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:26:in `require'
         29: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
         28: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
         27: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
         26: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
         25: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
         24: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activestorage-6.1.3.1/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb:354:in `<main>'
         23: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
         22: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
         21: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
         20: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:66:in `execute_hook'
         19: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:61:in `with_execution_control'
         18: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
         17: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `class_eval'
         16: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activestorage-6.1.3.1/lib/active_storage/engine.rb:123:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
         15: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/configuration_file.rb:18:in `parse'
         14: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/configuration_file.rb:22:in `parse'
         13: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/configuration_file.rb:43:in `render'
         12: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/erb.rb:905:in `result'
         11: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/erb.rb:905:in `eval'
         10: from /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/config/storage.yml:12:in `<main>'
          9: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb:309:in `method_missing'
          8: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:38:in `options'
          7: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:33:in `config'
          6: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:21:in `read'
          5: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:54:in `read'
          4: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:92:in `decrypt'
          3: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:22:in `decrypt_and_verify'
          2: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:154:in `decrypt_and_verify'
          1: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:198:in `_decrypt'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:198:in `final': OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError
        107: from bin/rails:2:in `<main>'
        106: from bin/rails:2:in `load'
        105: from /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
        104: from /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/bin/spring:7:in `tap'
        103: from /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
        102: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
        101: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
        100: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
         99: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
         98: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
         97: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
         96: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
         25: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
         24: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activestorage-6.1.3.1/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb:354:in `<main>'
         23: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
         22: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
         21: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
         20: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:66:in `execute_hook'
         19: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:61:in `with_execution_control'
         18: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
         17: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `class_eval'
         16: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activestorage-6.1.3.1/lib/active_storage/engine.rb:123:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
         15: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/configuration_file.rb:18:in `parse'
         14: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/configuration_file.rb:22:in `parse'
         13: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/configuration_file.rb:43:in `render'
         12: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/erb.rb:905:in `result'
         11: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/erb.rb:905:in `eval'
         10: from /home/louis/RubymineProjects/Oktotweet/config/storage.yml:12:in `<main>'
          9: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb:309:in `method_missing'
          8: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:38:in `options'
          7: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:33:in `config'
          6: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:21:in `read'
          5: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:54:in `read'
          4: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:92:in `decrypt'
          3: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:22:in `decrypt_and_verify'
          2: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:154:in `decrypt_and_verify'
          1: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:180:in `_decrypt'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:203:in `rescue in _decrypt': ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage (ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage)
```

I have seen a lot of tutorials that need a web server or more gems... But I just want to launch the server in production with a port number that all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54277392/rails-activesupportmessageencryptorinvalidmessage