# <ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage Error when deploying to Heroku Rails 5.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm having a good bit of trouble deploying my React on Rails App to Heroku. I have read and attempted countless posts on how to fix the secret_key_base and rails_master_key issues:

[ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54277392/activesupportmessageencryptorinvalidmessage)

[Running a rails server in production locally (InvalidMessage error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50102639/running-a-rails-server-in-production-locally-invalidmessage-error)

Not having any luck with any of these and there seems to be a good bit of debate over a lot of practices used to fix these issues (judging by the answers I've read).

Here's the error I'm getting in my Heroku logs:

```
2019-10-23T15:27:31.187947+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-10-23 15:27:31 +0000: Rack app error handling request { GET / }
2019-10-23T15:27:31.18796+00:00 app[web.1]: #<ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage>
2019-10-23T15:27:31.187962+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:206:in `rescue in _decrypt'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.187964+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:184:in `_decrypt'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.187966+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:157:in `decrypt_and_verify'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.187968+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:21:in `decrypt_and_verify'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.187971+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/secrets.rb:44:in `decrypt'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.187973+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/secrets.rb:81:in `preprocess'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.187975+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/secrets.rb:29:in `block in parse'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.187977+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/secrets.rb:26:in `each'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.187979+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/secrets.rb:26:in `each_with_object'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.187981+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/secrets.rb:26:in `parse'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.187983+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:399:in `secrets'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.187985+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:252:in `env_config'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.187987+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:706:in `build_request'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.18799+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:608:in `build_request'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.187992+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:523:in `call'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.187994+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.187996+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:660:in `handle_request'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.187997+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:474:in `process_client'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.187999+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.188001+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.447079+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=glacial-woodland-16769.herokuapp.com request_id=922c9b94-3b2b-43fd-9cec-b5eb2d78e21f fwd="8.20.20.246" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=16ms status=500 bytes=154 protocol=https
2019-10-23T15:27:31.445658+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-10-23 15:27:31 +0000: Rack app error handling request { GET /favicon.ico }
2019-10-23T15:27:31.445671+00:00 app[web.1]: #<ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage>
2019-10-23T15:27:31.445673+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:206:in `rescue in _decrypt'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.445675+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:184:in `_decrypt'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.445677+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:157:in `decrypt_and_verify'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.445679+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:21:in `decrypt_and_verify'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.445681+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/secrets.rb:44:in `decrypt'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.445683+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/secrets.rb:81:in `preprocess'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.445685+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/secrets.rb:29:in `block in parse'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.445687+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/secrets.rb:26:in `each'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.445688+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/secrets.rb:26:in `each_with_object'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.44569+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/secrets.rb:26:in `parse'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.445693+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:399:in `secrets'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.445695+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:252:in `env_config'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.445697+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:706:in `build_request'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.445699+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:608:in `build_request'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.445701+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:523:in `call'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.445703+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.445705+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:660:in `handle_request'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.445707+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:474:in `process_client'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.445709+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
2019-10-23T15:27:31.446389+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Would appreciate any help and can provide any details I might have left out. I'm relatively new to Heroku so I might just be overlooking something obvious, and I apologize if that is the case!

Answer (score 4):

IN my case we had a multi-environment credentials setup.

One for development, staging, and production.

The master.key works for the main

```
 credentials.yml file
```

The other environments have there own key, so for staging we used the `staging.key` in the

> RAILS_MASTER_KEY ON heroku.

For normal use try  the following :

copy data from credentails.yml file
delete credentials.yml and master.key

Use `Editor='code --wait' rails credentails:edit`
relplace code with your editor name.

paste credentails data in credentails file.

Answer (score 0):

1. remove this file:

```
$ rm config/credentials.yml.enc
```

2. re-generate this file:

```
$ EDITOR="vim" bundle exec rails credentials:edit
```

then try again

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using an old outdated master key

What I did is removing `config/credentials.yml.enc` then updating my `config/master.key` with the new key then ran `EDITOR="vim" rails credentials:edit` and it was all good